# Binary search tree for a series of methods

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I was working for a LONG time on this BST methods but apparently I'm getting almost everyone of them wrong. it looks like it should be working fine. If someone could help me that would be great.

```
BinaryTree(E item){
    data = item;
    left = new BinaryTree<E>();
    right = new BinaryTree<E>();
  }

  BinaryTree(E item, BinaryTree<E> left, BinaryTree<E> right)
  {
    data = item;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
public int weightBalanceFactor(){
   int thisWeight = Math.abs(left.nodeCount() - right.nodeCount());
  int weirdWeight = Math.abs(left.weightBalanceFactor()
    - right.weightBalanceFactor());
  return Math.max(thisWeight, weirdWeight);
 }

public int nodeSum(){
    int thisInt = Integer.parseInt((String) data);
  return thisInt + left.nodeSum() + right.nodeSum();
    }
```

This one gets the path with the max value

```
 public int maxPathSum(){
  int thisInt = Integer.parseInt((String) data);
  return Math.max(thisInt + left.maxPathSum(),
    thisInt + right.maxPathSum());
    }
```

This other methods should only return the transversals in each order

```
  public String preOrder(){
 String buffer = data.toString();
  String leftBuffer = left.preOrder();
  String rightBuffer = right.preOrder();
  if (leftBuffer != "")
   buffer += "\n" + leftBuffer;
  if (rightBuffer != "")
   buffer += "\n" + rightBuffer;
  return buffer;


  }
public String inOrder(){
    String leftBuffer = left.inOrder();
  String buffer = "";
  String rightBuffer = right.inOrder();
  if (leftBuffer != "")
   buffer += leftBuffer + "\n";
  buffer += data.toString();
  if (rightBuffer != "")
   buffer += "\n" + rightBuffer;
  return buffer;}


public String postOrder(){
        String leftBuffer = left.postOrder();
  String rightBuffer = right.postOrder();
  String buffer = "";
  if (leftBuffer != "")
   buffer += leftBuffer + "\n";
  if (rightBuffer != "")
   buffer += rightBuffer + "\n";
  buffer += data.toString();
  return buffer;
       }
```

Comment: What happens? What do you expect to happen? What's the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more specific in my question. The problem with the maxPathSum() and the nodesum() is that apparently is not returning an integer.I think is that I'm doing the parseint() sintax wrong because the program crashes when it returns the data of the node. The other methods give me a NullPointerException so I have tried to track down where the error is coming from and apparently it is going to the left of the tree and then crashes: ex:

Comment: /
      18
      \
   /
   83
   \
      /
      63
      \
         /
         29
         \
/
34
\
      /
      32
      \
   /
   74
   \

Comment: Sorry tried building a tree hahaha didn't work. Well, it goes from the root to the first child on the left and if the left child is a leaf then it crashes

Comment: also, sorry I didn't specify what each method actually did. the WBF looks for the longest and shortest path of a tree and then returns the difference. The node sum(), sums all the values of the tree (the problem is that the data in the trees is not always ints so I have to convert it to ints or return a warning if its not int, thus the parseint()) The maxpathsum() looks for the path with the max sum on a tree from root to leaf. And the transversal methods have to return a string in its respective order. (With every method but the sums it always crashes when it finds a leaf)

Comment: It is better if you can edit and improve your question instead of making comments under it. It will improve readability.